# Python: Importing everything from a python namespace / package

Tags: python, namespaces, package

all.

I'd think that this could be answered easily, but it isn't. As long as I've been searching for an answer, I keep thinking that I'm overlooking something simple.

I have a python workspace with the following package structure:

```
    MyTestProject
        /src
           /TestProjectNamespace
              __init__.py
              Module_A.py
              Module_B.py

    SecondTestProject
        /src
           /SecondTestProjectNamespace
              __init__.py
              Module_1.py
              Module_2.py
              ...
              Module_10.py
```

Note that MyTestProjectNamespace has a reference to SecondTestProjectNamespace.

In MyTestProjectNamespace, I need to import everything in SecondTestProjectNamespace. I could import one module at a time with the following statement(s):

```
    from SecondTestProjectNamespace.Module_A import *
    from SecondTestProjectNamespace.Module_B import *
```

...but this isn't practical if the SecondTestProject has 50 modules in it.

Does Python support a way to import everything in a namespace / package? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally using `import *` is discouraged, since it clutters up the namespace. And if a project has 50 modules in it, and you want to import everything in all 50 of those modules, that's a lot of clutter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can roll this using pkgutil.

Here's an example that lists all packages under twisted (except tests), and imports them:

```
# -*- Mode: Python -*-
# vi:si:et:sw=4:sts=4:ts=4

import pkgutil
import twisted

for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
    path=twisted.__path__,
    prefix=twisted.__name__+'.',
    onerror=lambda x: None):
        # skip tests
        if modname.find('test') > -1: 
            continue
        print(modname)
        # gloss over import errors
        try:
            __import__(modname)
        except:
            print 'Failed importing', modname
            pass

# show that we actually imported all these, by showing one subpackage is imported
print twisted.python
```

I have to agree with the other posters that star imports are a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Sorry it took me so long to get back to you.

At the end of the day, I simply have to import each class from the modules I want to use. Init.py can help with that, as you spelled out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It is possible to set up SecondTestProject to automatically import everything in its submodules, by putting code in `__init__.py` to do the `from ... import *` you mention.  It's also possible to automate this to some extent using the `__import__` function and/or the `imp` module.  But there is no quick and easy way to take a package that *isn't* set up this way and make it work this way.

It's probably not a good idea anyway.  If you have 50 modules, importing everything from all of them into your global namespace is going to cause a proliferation of names, and very likely conflicts among those names.

Comment: Thanks, Bren. Yes, I'm a python newbie. I'll spell this out further: 

Pretend that I have 50 modules in SecondTestProjectNamespace. Each module has a single class defined inside it, where Module_A.py has a class inside it named Module_A. I want to reference all of my *modules* from SecondTestNamespace in another module, so I can create new instances of them and manipulate them. I thought an import statement was the best way to do that.

If there's a better way, please tell me.

Comment: @BobaFett: Why do you have only one class in each module?  This is often a Java mindset that people erroneously apply to Python.  In Python, it's perfectly fine to have lots of classes in the same module.

Comment: You can't make an instance of a module.

Answer (score 1):

As other had put it - it might not be a good idea. But there are ways of keeping your namespaces and therefore avoiding naming conflicts - and having all the modules/sub-packages in a module available to the package user with a single import.

Let's suppose I have a package named "pack", within it a module named "a.py" defining some "b" variable. All I want to do is :

```
>>> import pack
>>> pack.a.b
1
```

One way of doing this is to put in `pack/__init__.py` a line that says
`import a` - thus in your case you'd need fifty such lines, and keep them up to date.

Not that bad.

However, the documentation at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package  - says that if you have a string list named `__all__` in your `__init__.py` file, all module/sub-package names in that list are imported when one does `from pack import *`

That alone would half-work - but would require users of your package to perform the not-recommended "from x import *" form.

But -- you can do the "... import *" inside `__init__.py` itself, after defining the `__all__` variable - so all you have to do is to keep the `__all__` up to date:

With the `TestProjectNamespace/__init__.py` being like this:

```
__all__ = ["Module_A", "Module_B", ...]
from TestProjectNamespace import *
```

your users would have 
TestProjectNamespace.Module_A (and others) available upon import of TestProjectNamespace.

And, of course - you could automate the creation of `__all__` - it is just a variable, after all - but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Thanks, Jsbueno. How would I make Module1, Module2, etc. available to TestProjectNamespace? Note that Module1, Module2, etc. are in the *SecondTestProjectNamespace* package, not TestProjectNamespace.

Comment: If you use the same technique on `SecondTest...`, from `TestProject` you can do `import SecontTestProjectNameSpace` and use ``SecondTestProjectNameSpace.Module_1` - or you can import * from SecondTest.. as well

Answer (score 0):

> Does Python support a way to import everything in a namespace / package?

No. A package is not a super-module -- it's a collection of modules grouped together.

---

At least part of the reason is that it's not trivial to determine what 'everything' means inside a folder: there are problems like network drives, soft links, hard links, ...